# Wait for query in Node.js MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

When I run this right now the page renders before it can receive the data from MySQL. The loop goes for all the files in a folder and finds that data in the How can I make it wait for the data to be sent before loading the webpage?

```
app.get('/explore', function(req,res){
  var fileNames = new Array();
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
      fs.readdirSync('./files').forEach(file => {
        if (err) throw err;
        var requester = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE dbname = '" + file + "'";
        pool.query(requester, function (err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          fileNames.push(result[0].name);
        });
        connection.release();
      });
    });
  res.render('explore', { fileNames : fileNames })
});
```

Comment: It seems you didn't fully understand asynchronous code yet. The callbacks run later in time, but the rest continues before that. So, right now you are actually calling `connection.release()` immediately, before the query is even finished, and in the same way you are calling `res.render` immediately, before `pool.getConnection` even completed and the queries even started, and the queries are executing in parallel.

Comment: Trying to fix this, especially with the loop here, the code will quickly get ugly in the callback style that you are using. Look into promises and async/await instead, then the code can be written correctly in a very neat and tidy way.

Comment: Also, you have an SQL injection vulnerability there (in case the contents of the `files` folder are user data). You should never concatenate a string into an SQL query. You have to escape the string, or better, use compiled statements/parameterized queries. Any modern SQL library will allow to do that. You write for example `WHERE dbname = ?` and provide the `file` in a separate parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can make minor corrections in the code so that it renders as intended.

```
app.get('/explore', function(req,res){
  var fileNames = new Array();
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
      fs.readdirSync('./files').forEach(file => {
        if (err) throw err;
        var requester = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE dbname = '" + file + "'";
        pool.query(requester, function (err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          fileNames.push(result[0].name);
          res.render('explore', { fileNames : fileNames })
          //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
        });
        connection.release();
      });
    });
});
```